# Making a new dictionary out of a List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have a **list of dictionaries**:

```
dicti = [{**'product':** 'Cereal', 'price': 12.99},
     {**'product'**: 'Cereal1', 'price': 9.99}, 
     {**'product'**: 'Cereal2', 'price': 11.99},
     {**'product'**: 'Cereal', 'price' : 15.83}, 
     {**'product'**: 'Cereal1', 'price': 10.99}, 
     {**'product'**: 'Cereal2', 'price': 9.99}]
```

My goal is to find the product with the **top total of sales**:

```
Output = [Cereal, 28.82]
```

So far, I have been able to extract dictionaries to a list:

```
list = [['Cereal',12.99,'Cereal1',9.99,'Cereal2', 11.99,'Cereal', 15.83, 'Cereal1, 10.99,'Cereal2',9.99]
```

Is this a proper way? or What is the best way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to accumulate the `price` for each `product`, then take the [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) at the end:

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

dicti = [
    {"product": "Cereal", "price": 12.99},
    {"product": "Cereal1", "price": 9.99},
    {"product": "Cereal2", "price": 11.99},
    {"product": "Cereal", "price": 15.83},
    {"product": "Cereal1", "price": 10.99},
    {"product": "Cereal2", "price": 9.99},
]

counts = Counter()
for x in dicti:
    counts[x["product"]] += x["price"]

print(max(counts.items(), key=itemgetter(1)))
# ('Cereal', 28.82)
```

If you want the result to be a `list` instead of `tuple`:

```
print(list(max(counts.items(), key=itemgetter(1))))
# ['Cereal', 28.82]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 import pandas as pd
 dicti = [{'product': 'Cereal', 'price': 12.99},
 {'product': 'Cereal1', 'price': 9.99}, 
 {'product': 'Cereal2', 'price': 11.99},
 {'product': 'Cereal', 'price' : 15.83}, 
 {'product': 'Cereal1', 'price': 10.99}, 
 {'product': 'Cereal2', 'price': 9.99}]

 sd = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dicti  )

 sd.groupby('product').sum()
```

This will give you the sum as expect

Cereal  28.82
Cereal1 20.98
Cereal2 21.98